# Creating users using the Softlayer Python Client

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I use the following command to create a new SL user primarily for VPN access using the python client:
user_sldata = client['SoftLayer_User_Customer'].createObject(userInfo,password,password)

The command works successfully but sends an email to the email account with the subject "New User Password Request". Is that behaviour expected? Is this a change to how the backend deals with new user requests, as this step didn't use to be required...

thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a new feature, every time that an user is created, an email is sent in order to set his password.